# Tutorial on how to implement the ability to draw a picture on a website with a mouse using Django

Tags: django, graphics

I want to create a 28x28 grid on my website (created with Django) where a visitor can use their mouse to draw an image (like the number 7) in the grid, then save it in the sqllite database with a label entered in an adjacent text box via a button. The data format would be 785 interger values: the first integer is the label while the 784 values are pixel grayscale intensity values throughout the grid.

I want the ability as the admin to view these data entrys as the drawn images on the website and delete the ones I want to delete.

Where can I figure out how to do this? I only picked up Django two days ago and have followed a tutorial to make a simple poll app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use html canvas. You can just use basic canvas or a package built on top of canvas. Canvas is not the easiest thing to work with but like anything else can be done with practice. I have done a good amount of work with canvas and know this can be done with it. I have not personally used this tutorial but it looks good https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-web-based-drawing-application-using-canvas--net-14288
also the docs because that's always a good place to look. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API